# Download full diff from Github

Tags: github

Github supports downloading a [diff/patch](https://github.com/blog/967-github-secrets) for given pull request, but this diff/patch only contain limited context lines, is there a way or tool which could download the full diff then I can open it offline without any dependency on the repo?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so:

As mentioned in "[Diff and patch media types](https://developer.github.com/changes/2012-12-10-Diff-and-patch-media-types/)", you can get `.diff` and `.patch` content directly from the API for the following resources:

- [Commits](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit)
- [Commit comparisons](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits)
- [Pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#get-a-single-pull-request)

However, nowhere in those API definition would you see a "context" parameter which would enable you to get more lines around each diff.